# Careers "Edit Company Page" should clarify the order of tech stack items is important

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

In the "Edit Tech Stack" widget on the Company Page edit page you can list all technologies your company uses through Stack Overflow tags. This is then listed on your company page. For example, this is the one for [Stack Exchange](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange?c=62IeP5BU9xQoV2):

[image: Stack Exchange tech stack]

The ordering is similar to what I'd do on a company page: with a sort of "grouping" from left-to-right. But this doesn't necessarily imply the tags are listed in order of importance.

When viewing company search results you'll notice though that the first three tags are listed, which kind of implies they *are* most important. For example see [this search](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/companies?searchTerm=Stack%20Exchange):

[image: Company search result]

It would be nice if either:

- The "Edit Tech Stack" section company/edit would indicate the first three tags will be listed as "main" tags; or
- There would be a seperate "Main Tags" field for company pages where you can only enter three tags (possibly inline in the "Edit Tech Stack" widget, or as a seperate widget).